# Issue creating a list of dictionaries in ansible using Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries in Ansible by parsing 2 lists and below is the code.

```yaml
- name: Create list of data dictionary 
  vars:
     _sinfo: |-
       {% for data in data_list|default([]) %}
       {%- if item in data['subject'] %}
       [{ grade: {{data['grade']}}, id: {{data['id']}}, subject: {{data['subject']}} }]
       {%- endif -%}
       {% endfor %}
  set_fact:
    data_dict_list: "{{ data_dict_list|default([]) + _sinfo|list}}"
  with_items: 
    - "{{ subject_list }}"
```

Above script gives me a list of dictionary with each string broken into letters and using

```yaml
data_dict_list: "{{ data_dict_list|default([]) + _sinfo|list|join}}"
```

Gives me error

> ```
> msg: 'Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ data_dict_list|default([]) + _sinfo | list | join}}): can only concatenate list (not "unicode") to list'
> ```

List values: `[u''Physics'', u''Chemistry'', u''Biology'', u''Math'', u''Geology'']`

Inventory file:

```yaml
data_list:
  - id: 31
    grade: ['A+']
    subject: Physics
  - id: 40
    grade: ['B']
    subject: Math
  - id: 30
    grade: ['A']
    subject: Biology
  - id: 33
    grade: ['A+']
    subject: Physics
  - id: 35
    grade: ['A+', 'B+']
    subject: Physics
```

Note:
Ansible version:  2.7.7
Python version: 2.7.18
Jinja2 version: 2.11.2

What I am trying to do is to group data by subject and create a list of subjects with each subject dictionary containing all the data with that subject.

Comment: `_sinfo` is not a list it is just a really big string, this is why running `list` on the string gives you a list of characters.

Comment: It is supposed to be a list with a single dictionary

Comment: It is just multiline string, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/2123530

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε It clarified few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"Group data by subject and **create a list of subjects** with each **subject dictionary** containing all the data with that subject"*

A: The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list_subj: "{{ list_subj|default([]) + [{item.0: item.1}] }}"
      loop: "{{ data_list|groupby('subject') }}"
    - debug:
        var: list_subj
```

give the list of the dictionaries

```yaml
  list_subj:
  - Biology:
    - grade:
      - A
      id: 30
      subject: Biology
  - Math:
    - grade:
      - B
      id: 40
      subject: Math
  - Physics:
    - grade:
      - A+
      id: 31
      subject: Physics
    - grade:
      - A+
      id: 33
      subject: Physics
    - grade:
      - A+
      - B+
      id: 35
      subject: Physics
```

---

However, a dictionary might be more practical here. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dict_subj: "{{ dict(data_list|groupby('subject')) }}"
    - debug:
        var: dict_subj
```

give

```yaml
  dict_subj:
    Biology:
    - grade:
      - A
      id: 30
      subject: Biology
    Math:
    - grade:
      - B
      id: 40
      subject: Math
    Physics:
    - grade:
      - A+
      id: 31
      subject: Physics
    - grade:
      - A+
      id: 33
      subject: Physics
    - grade:
      - A+
      - B+
      id: 35
      subject: Physics
```

Comment: Thanks but i still get the output with strings being broken down to individual characters. What does " [{item.0: item.1}] " do?

Comment: What's preventing you from taking a look at `- debug: msg: "{{ [{item.0: item.1}] }}"` in the loop?

Comment: I am new to ansible so was not sure how you can debug within a loop but now i figured that out and thanks for the help. Using dictionary as you suggested worked better.